# Ember.run.later behavior in testing

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I built a simple flash message service in an Ember-CLI application based on this post:
https://medium.com/delightful-ui-for-ember-apps/adding-flash-messages-to-an-ember-app-437b13e49c1b

As the code in the post shows, the service relies on Ember.run.later to destroy the messages after a specified period of time.

I use this service in various parts of my application, on route and controller levels.

I wanted to test this functionality with some integration tests. For example, on the Application route, a user can submit a search query to the backend. If the query isn't properly formed, then I throw an error using the flash message service. Similarly, I can check for if authentication was successful:

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`
`import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin'`

ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend ApplicationRouteMixin,
  setupController: (ctrl) ->
    flashes = @get 'flashes'
    ctrl.set 'flashes', flashes
  actions:
    error: (e) -> 
      if e.jqXHR and e.jqXHR.status is 404
        @get('flashes').warning('no data from the server')
    sessionAuthenticationFailed: (e) ->
      @get('flashes').danger('another relevant error message')

`export default ApplicationRoute`
```

To test this, I would simulate the desired behavior, and then check for the existence of the message:

```
test 'checking if the error appears on a 404', ->
  # series of steps that lead to a 404
  andThen ->
    equal(find('.ember-notify').text(), 'no data from the server')
```

Where 'ember-notify' is the class name of the div containing the flashed message.

I see the message pop up in the testing container as desired - and then the tests 'pause' until the message disappears. Which means that my test ends up failing, because it checks for the existence of the div *after* it disappears.

My understanding is that this is explained in this thread:
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5362

e.g., "Ember-testing checks for scheduled timers to finish before tearing down your app."

So my testing environment will always wait for Ember.run.later to finish.

Any thoughts / ideas on how to approach this? Is there a better way to test error events on the route level?

My thought was that I could directly test whether or not the error event was called on the Application route, for example, but I don't know how to do this (and how would I extend this pattern to testing on controllers, where I'm also using the flash message service?)

Thanks!